# Triangulation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, triangulation, triangulation-survey

I have a telemetry dataset for bats where one person stood at Point A and aimed his telemetry antenna to find the location of a bat. His/Her Lat/Lon coordinates and the angle relative to true North is recorded. Similarly for person B at another spot. So given two lat/lons and two angles the triangulation gives the location of the bat.

I looked up TIN in the 3D Analyst toolset and it just creates triangulation between all the points and expects elevation input which is not what I am looking for. The triangulation/third point is a new point not in this table and has to be calculated. Here is a sample of the data. You can see Bat 3 has moved between two locations here while the person(s) holding the telemetry antenna has simply moved it while standing at the same spot (observation based on the difference in the angle seen).

Can you point me to any toolset in ArcGIS Pro that can take this datasheet and find the location of the bat?

[image: Sample Dataset of above described points]

Comment: The TIN data type is completely wrong for this. The first and second problems of geodesy are exposed in the `arcpy.PointGeometry` class. You want to use the `pointFromAngleAndDistance()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this a tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

This is direct geodetic problem:

[image]

[image]

where Ctg(angle) is Cos(angle)/Sin(angle).

Formulae is very long and easy to mess up, so as suggested by @Vince will use pointFromAngleAndDistance() method to draw 2 rays coming from observer points and find their intersection point. I suggest to use projected coordinate system and assume that your tables are structured as follows:

[image]

Place N bats somewhere, their location doesn't matter:

[image]

and run this script:

```
import pandas as pd
maxDistance = 1.0e4
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(2193) #projected coordinats system factory numbe
def makeRay(nXYA):
    i,n,x,y,a = nXYA
    pS = arcpy.Point(x,y)
    pG = arcpy.PointGeometry(pS,SR)
    pE = pG.pointFromAngleAndDistance (a, maxDistance,'PLANAR').firstPoint
    pLine = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([pS,pE]),SR)
    return pLine
# get all observers coordinates and angles
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("OBSERVERS",['GRP_NO','POINT_X','POINT_Y','BEARING'])
DF = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
#iterate through pairs of observers
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("INITIAL_POINTS",("Shape@","GRP_NO")) as cursor:
    for shp,no in cursor:
        df = DF[DF.GRP_NO==no]
        if not df.BEARING.std(): continue #parallel lines handling
        twoRows = [row for row in df.itertuples()]
        lineA,lineB = map(makeRay,twoRows)
        isectP = lineA.intersect(lineB,1).firstPoint
        thisPoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(isectP,SR)
        cursor.updateRow((thisPoint,no))
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed reply. Truly appreciate it. -Prabha

Comment: Could you please clarify how you set up the "Initial Points attribute table to reference in the script?

Comment: Just use field names shown, e.g. create new field GRP_NO and populate it by values from your Grupo. Same applies to layers names in your table of content.

Comment: Understood. I think my question was not clear in the first place. Did you create the "INITIAL_POINTS" table by running the PointGeometry-pointFromAngleAndDistance() method? Meaning- Do I need to first create the INITIAL_POINTS table before running the Pandas script? Or will the script create it since it is using PointGeometry.

Comment: Create N random points anywhere inside your country and call them INITIAL_POINTS

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try! This site and the service all of you provide are invaluable to GIS-passionate users like me.  Your time and effort is very much appreciated. Hope I can pay it forward. -Prabha

Comment: I setup both tables and ran the script and i get this system error mesg. I did set the spatial reference to my specific map one. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 90, in _get
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(getattr(self._arc_object, attr_name))
SystemError: <built-in function getattr> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: See updated script, I've added 1 line of code to handle parallel rays.

Comment: I see the change, will incorporate and keep u posted. Thank you.

Comment: Setting map projection is not enough, your coordinates, layers must also be in this projected system, I.e meters, not decimal degrees

Comment: Yes, both layers-Observers and Initial_Points are in the projected coordinate system as mentioned in the script and units are in "meters".

Comment: I ran the modified script. No errors but no output either. I am not seeing the Initial_Points modified to show the new locations for the points after the intersection. Basically, nothing seems to be given out as output.

Comment: So, the points remain where they were? Refresh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149104/discussion-between-prabhav-and-felixip).